# Partially ordered set exercise

Tags: self-learning, order-theory

Hi everyone is my first time working with posets and I'd like to know if the solution of the next exercise is really correct or maybe there is some errors that I cannot see. Thank in advance.

Exercise; Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a function. Suppose that $Y$ is a poset with some ordering relation $\le_Y$. Define the relation $x\le_X x' \iff f(x)<_Yf(x') \lor x=x'$. (1) Shows that the relation turns $X$ into a partially ordered set. If we know in addition that the relation $\le_Y$ makes $Y$ totally ordered (2) does this means that the relation $\le_x$ makes $X$ into a totally ordered set? If not, (3) what additional assumption needs to be made on $f$ to ensure that $\le_X$ makes $X$ totally ordered?

(1) We need to check that $(X, \le_X)$ is a poset. Clearly the relation is reflexive. We will show that the relation is anti-symmetric. For the sake of contradiction suppose that $x\not= x'$ and, $x\le_X x'$ and $x'\le_X x$, in other words we  thus have $f(x)<_Yf(x')$ and $f(x')<_Yf(x)$, i.e., $f(x)<_Yf(x)$ which is a contradiction. Now we wish to show that the relation is transitive. Suppose $x\le_X x'$ and $x'\le_X x''$ [notice that if $x'=x$ there is nothing to prove] we may assume $f(x)<_Yf(x')$. Then either $x'=x''$ or $f(x')<_Yf(x'')$. For the former the result is trivial and for the latter the result follows by the transitivity of $\le_Y$ and to show that the equality $f(x)=f(x'')$ yields a contradiction.

(2) Counterexample: Let $f: \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}; \;(i,j)\mapsto i$, and we define the natural ordering on  $\mathbb{N}$. Then clearly $\mathbb{N}$ is total. Let $(i,j), (i,k) \in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$, where $k\not=j$, then both maps to $i$, so  the elements are not comparable.

(3) We claim that the additional hypothesis that $f$ is injective it will sufficient.

Suppose in addition that $f$ is an injective function and let $x,x'\in X$, notice that if $x=x'$ there is nothing to prove, for that reason we may assume that $x\not= x'$. Then $f(x)\not= f(x')$ and since $f(x),f(x')\in Y$ and $Y$ is totally ordered, then either $f(x)<_Yf(x')$ in which case $x<_X x' $ or $f(x')<_Yf(x)$ which give us the same result just with the roles of $x, x'$ interchanging. Hence $X$ is totally ordered.

Comment: Seems correct to me :)

Comment: It is correct, well done!

Comment: Ok Thanks for your help :)