# Are sets that map to partially ordered sets themselves partially ordered sets?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

This is a question from Terry Tao's analysis. Here is the question:

> Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a function from one set $X$ to another set $Y$. Suppose that $Y$ is partially ordered with some ordering relation $\leq_Y$. Define a relation $\leq_X$ on X by defining $x \leq_X x'$ if and only if $f(x) \leq_Y f(x')$. Show that this relation $\leq_X$ turns $X$ into a partially ordered set. If we know in addition that the relation $\leq_Y$ makes $Y$ totally ordered, does this mean that the relation $\leq_X$ makes $X$ totally ordered also? If not, what additional assumptions need to be made on $f$ in order to ensure that $\leq_X$ makes $X$ totally ordered?

So to prove reflexivity of x we have:

$f(x) \leq_Y f(x) \Longleftrightarrow x \leq_X x$ and so reflexivity is proven as Y is partially ordered.

To prove transitivity:

If $f(x) \leq_Y f(y)$ and $f(y) \leq_Y f(z)$ then $f(x) \leq_Y f(z)$ by the definition of a partially ordered set. Hence, by the definition of the order on $X$, we obtain if $x \leq_X y$ and $y \leq_X z$ then $x \leq_X z$, proving transitivity.

However, I am having some trouble proving anti-symmetry.

We note that if $f(x) \leq_Y f(y)$ and $f(y) \leq_Y f(x)$ then $f(x) = f(y)$. However, this does not necessarily prove that $x=y$. Do we not have to assume that $f$ is an injective function?

So as a counterexample, consider $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and $Y=\{1,2\}$ (and let $Y$ have the normal ordering of the natural numbers), and let the function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be defined as $f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2, f(3) = 1$. We then must have $1 \leq_X 3$ as $f(1) \leq_Y f(3)$, and similarly we must have $3 \leq_X 1$ as $f(3) \leq_Y f(1)$, but clearly $1 \neq 3$.

I'm especially confused as [this proof from this SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633415/partially-ordered-set-exercise) was said to be correct, but doesn't the counterexample show this to be false?

Then, once we have assumed the function to be injective, this makes X a totally ordered set when Y is a totally ordered set. Simply as either $f(x) \leq_Y f(y)$ or $f(y) \leq_Y f(x)$, which implies that either $x \leq_X y$ or $y \leq_X x$.

I feel as though I am missing something major though, just because I'm sure I'm not right against the textbook and the other question. I just can't see where I went wrong, and need some help with that. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is a difference between your problem and the linked one.  The order in $X$ is defined as $x\leq y$ if and only if $f(x)<f(y)$ or $x=y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $f(x) \leq_Y f(x) \Longleftrightarrow x \leq_X x$ and so reflexivity is proven as Y is partially ordered.

It would probably be more sensible to write $x\leq_X x\iff f(x)\leq_Y f(x)$, but technically, you're right.

---

> If $f(x) \leq_Y f(y)$ and $f(y) \leq_Y f(z)$ then $f(x) \leq_Y f(z)$ by the definition of a partially ordered set. Hence, by the definition of the order on $X$, we obtain if $x \leq_X y$ and $y \leq_X z$ then $x \leq_X z$, proving transitivity.

Again, this sort of seems backward. I would write it so it is more clear that:

- We start with $x\leq_X y$ and $y \leq_X z$
- This, by definition, means that $f(x)\leq_Yf(y)$ and $f(y)\leq_Yf(z)$
- This, because $\leq_Y$ is partial ordering, means that $f(x)\leq_Yf(z)$
- This, by definition, means $x\leq_Xz$.

That way, you can clearly show how each step follows from the previous.

---

For anti-symmetry, you are entirely correct, if $f$ is not injective, then you cannot conclude that $\leq_X$ is a partial ordering. Your counterexample is sufficient.

I don't really know what's confusing you, since the linked question assumes that $x\leq_X x'$ if and only if $f(x)<_Y f(x')$ **OR** $x=x'$ which is different from the definition you are working with.

Comment: $<_Y$. With $\leq_Y$ his counter example still applies.

Comment: @Hellen You're right, a typo.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread that as being identical to my question. I now understand and am no longer confused. Also, thank you for the help in proof technique. I have been self-teaching real analysis with not much experience in abstract math, so some of my technique may be slightly iffy. Thanks.